# Issue facing in Selenium handling multiple window

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

I have written the below script where first i will click on FACEBOOK  Sign in button then the pop up for FACEBOOK login page will open in a separate window.I am entering the id and password. But my issue is when i am clicking on the login button then that window will disappear and my parent window URL will change. How to handle the changed URL. I need to perform some operation on that. I am aware that i can move to parent window,but the issue is when i click on login the URL changes

```
private  void facebookSignIn(){

        WebElement element=null;
        try{
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signin_facebook_button']/div[2]"));
            String mwh=driver.getWindowHandle();
            element.click();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            Set<String> set=driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> iterator=set.iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                String popupHandle=iterator.next().toString();
                if(!popupHandle.contains(mwh))
                {
                    driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);

                    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']"));
                    element.sendKeys(account);

                    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']"));
                    element.sendKeys(password);

                    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_2']"));
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                    countDownLatch.await();
                    element.click();
                    System.out.println("Click Done");
                    //driver.switchTo().window(mwh);
                }
            }
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            counter++;
            if(counter==1)
            {
                startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            WebElement sso_logout = (new WebDriverWait(driver,30)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sso_logout")));
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

            try{
                element = driver.findElement(By.id("sso_logout"));
                element.click();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception from SSO_Logout");
            }

            double temp=(double)(end-start)/1000;
            latencyMap.put(Thread.currentThread().getName(),temp) ;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-->Done");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            countDownLatch.countDown();
            totalNumberOfUsers--;
            System.out.println(account);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does the changing url effects you? Its not very clear.

Comment: After clicking on Facebook log in window that window will close and the parent window URL will change at the same moment after sign in. Now i need to do some operation after sign in. How to handle the window that i am getting after sigin in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WindowHandle` is not based on url, so it shouldn't effect you. If you need to switch back do something like that:

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// switch to the new window
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!winHandle.equals(parentHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}

//do something with the new window
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']"));
element.sendKeys(account);

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']"));
element.sendKeys(password);

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_2']"));
countDownLatch.countDown();
countDownLatch.await();
element.click();
System.out.println("Click Done");

// switch back to the old window
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);

// if the new window is closed by its on
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());
```

`WindowHandle` example:

> "CDwindow-0D7BB6F6-A7E0-4DCE-B4D0-F202E85D982D"

Comment: Basically the problem comes when i do driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); I am getting the  parent window,but what is happening the moment i click on log in the parent url  changes . I need that page of the new URL not the older one

Comment: @VikashMishra try `driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());` after the URL has changed.

Comment: @VikashMishra did you have any errors with the first solution? the different url doesn't spouse to have any effect, you are switching to browser window, not to website.

Comment: Thanks @guy . Yes first solution itself worked. The issue was with my id